# To find the locus of points on a complex plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers

To find the locus of points on a complex plane satisfying the following conditions:

$|z-1+i| \leq 3$;

$\Im((2-i)z) \geq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $$z=x+iy$$ then we get
$$|x-1+i(y-1)|\le 3$$ and $$(2-i)z=(2-i)(x+iy)=2x-ix+2iy+y$$
so you will have $$2y-x\geq 0$$
can you finish? 
and we get $$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\le 9$$ and $$y\geq \frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: Sonnhard Graubner I can not, unfortunately. And still need to show on the field

Comment: @xuguyepo Draw the picture: all the points over a line (last inequality) **that are also within a closed circle** (first inequality). And observe you've already *accepted* (green checkmark) and not simply *upvoted* this answer. If you accept a question maybe other members of the site won't even read your question as they understand you've already gotten a complete answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left|\text{z}-1+i\right|\le3\\
\\
\Im\left(\text{z}\cdot\left(2-i\right)\right)\ge0
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, we know that:

- $$\left|\text{z}-1+i\right|=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-1\right)^2+\left(\Im\left(\text{z}\right)+1\right)^2}\tag2$$
- $$\Im\left(\text{z}\cdot\left(2-i\right)\right)=2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\tag3$$

So, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-1\right)^2+\left(\Im\left(\text{z}\right)+1\right)^2}\le3\\
\\
2\cdot\Im\left(\text{z}\right)-\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\ge0
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Which also gives:

$$\left(\Im\left(\text{z}\right)+1\right)^2<9-\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-1\right)^2\tag5$$